# Mailchimp: is an invalid email address and cannot be imported

Tags: mailchimp

I added a bunch of email address to Mailchimp with success.  However, one that is absolutely a good email address which I can send regular email to fails.  Mailchimp states that it "is an invalid email address and cannot be imported."  Why?

Comment: What is the domain of the email? Can you try to add that manually through the website and check? Sometimes, it will treat certain emails as test emails or admin emails and reject them.

Comment: It is a gmail.com email addres.  I did try to add it by hand in our mailchimp account using the "Add a subscriber" form.  That is when I got the invalid address message.  It is strange.  We have used this simple form many times with success.  We have just one address it won't take.  Thank you for your attention.

Comment: It has happened to me as well. You can also try to import the contact using the "Import Contact" (copy and paste) menu and just add the email address field. Then when you check the import history, it will give some more details of why it did not accept it.

Comment: I tried to import from a csv file with the one address.  I got this message: "These contacts are already in your audience.  We have not added any contacts to your  ZZZZZZ audience.  However, that address is not in the audience.  I searched.

Comment: On the webpage, if you go to "Audience" -> "All Contacts" -> "Manage Contacts" -> "Import History", you can get more details of why MailChimp feels that this contact is already in your audience. Remember, it considers "archived", "unsubscribed", "forgotten", contacts also part of your MailChimp account. These details may or may not not show up in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Nikhil.  Your tips were great.  I'm still not sure why the import didn't work.  The suggestion from the import history was that it might be a Role-based email address.  It was not.  However, it led me to the idea of changing the email address on an existing email address.  That worked.

Comment: Seems like a really dirty workaround but that was the only thing which worked for me, too.